# To escape many _ in LaTeX efficiently

Tags: latex, escaping, tex

**How can you escape _ without the use of `\_`?**

This is the example of the question

> `word_a_a_a_a_a_b_c_dd`

There is one function which you can use for this. 
However, I cannot remember its name.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Are you thinking of the `underscore` package, which redefines the underscore symbol so that you don't have to escape it in text mode? See [**here**](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-underscore).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I will use this package in my next procject, since my current code breaks because it contains a lot of underscores espaces by `\_`.

Answer (score 26):

Other than verbatim I wouldn't know.

Verbatim environment:

```
\begin{verbatim}
  word_a_a_a_a_a_b_c_dd
\end{verbatim}
```

Inline:

```
\verb|word_a_a_a_a_a_b_c_dd|
```

Comment: A problem is that this doesn't work inside many things, like `\item[\verb|here|]` is illegal. See this answer for an alternative http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2252/15665 I use `\usepackage[Q=yes,pverb-linebreak=no]{examplep}` and `\item[\Q{this_works}]`

Answer (score 14):

I couldn't get the `underscore` package to work, so I used the `url` package:

```
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{sf}  % or rm, depending on your font

...

Foo \url{word_a_a_a_a_a_b_c_dd} bar.
```

Comment: Only issue here is that if you define the color of your urls elsewhere in the preamble, this will make them colored.

Answer (score 4):

It's funny how this is a question and answer site for programming questions but nobody has suggested programming yet.

You could define your own command which replaces the underscore tokens:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\filename}[1]{\emph{\replunderscores{#1}}}

\makeatletter
% \expandafter for the case that the filename is given in a command
\newcommand{\replunderscores}[1]{\expandafter\@repl@underscores#1_\relax}

\def\@repl@underscores#1_#2\relax{%
    \ifx \relax #2\relax
        % #2 is empty => finish
        #1%
    \else
        % #2 is not empty => underscore was contained, needs to be replaced
        #1%
        \textunderscore
        % continue replacing
        % #2 ends with an extra underscore so I don't need to add another one
        \@repl@underscores#2\relax
    \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \filename{__init__.py}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this is precisely what I needed. I wanted to define a command to add an URL in a footnote but keeping a regular font. `\newcommand{\footurl}[1]{\footnote{\href{#1}{\replunderscores{#1}}}}
`

Comment: @Tom I'm glad if my answer has helped you. Please keep in mind, though, that URLs can contain other characters where this approach does not work like `%` or `#`. So you may not always get around changing catcodes and simply speaking that does not work inside of arguments. The url package makes it easy to define a macro containing the URL where this is possible and then use the macro inside of the footnote without changing fonts if you wish so: `\urlstyle{same} ... \urldef{\myurl}\url{some%url#} ... \footnote{see \myurl}`

Answer (score 3):

Typically you want a monospaced font in such situations, so you can use this:

```
\verb|word_a_a_a_a_a_b_c_dd|
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also be thinking of the `lstlisting` or `verbatim` environments, which are commonly used to display code - which can contain underscores.  However, these environments do a lot more than just "escape" underscores.