# Escaping _ efficiently in Tabular environment, LaTeX

Tags: escaping, latex, tabular

**How can you escape underscores only in the tabular environment without the use of `\_`?**

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346512/to-escape-many-in-latex-efficiently) discusses about underscore in general.
I cannot use the environment *verbatim* nor the package underscore.

**Sample data**

```
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | p{5cm} |} 
\hline 
delete_a_question.php&poistaa kysymyksen&setterit \\ \hline 
edit_question.php&muokkaa kysymyst\"{a}&getterit, HTML koodin generointia \\ \hline 
--cut--
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\bgroup
  \catcode`\_=13%
  \def_{\textunderscore}%
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|p{4.5cm}}
    test_444 & 555 & 4_4\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\egroup

And now for some normal maths: $a_i=3$.
```

Here, I change the category code of the underscore character so that it is active (this means that I can give the underscore a macro definition). I define the underscore character to output an actual underscore character.

The `\bgroup` and `\egroup` limit the effects of redefining the underscore character.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than hacking with catcodes manually, the [underscore package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/underscore.html) does it for you so that `_` works in text as a printed underscore, while still behaving as a subscript modifier in maths mode. Just load the package.

Comment: Updated link to [underscore package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/underscore) :)